# How can I develop for Safari 6 without buying a mac?

Tags: windows, safari, ipad, web-development

I've always found that just developing in Windows, and using [Safari for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1531) has been sufficient.

However, [Safari 6](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/whats-new.html) has now been released, and I've got at least one user who has contacted me, saying he's experienced problems with one of my sites on his new ipad.

The trouble is that Safari for Windows only goes up to 5.1.7.

Do I have to go out and buy a new mac/ipad/iphone in order to test my code, or is there another way?

Comment: If the problem exsts on the iPad then you would need an iPad not a Mac.

Comment: You have three options. Tell your users to buy you a mac. Visit hackintosh.org and see if there is a bootable ISO for osx 10.7 that you can load in an emulator such as VirtualBox. And finally - declare that Safari 6 will not be supported until Apple release it for Windows.

Comment: My employer will not buy an ipad or mac. But they insist that I must support both.

Comment: @Ramhound Isn't Safari 6 the same on ipad as on a mac?

Comment: @Urbycoz: Until you're able to afford a better employer, I recommend reading Dilbert comics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both use webkit, but don't live and die by that. We have seen many errors\behaviors that only occur in safari.

Use browserstack or sauce labs. They have emulators\virtual desktops that can recreate your issues.

I'm here because 6.0+ changed the way it handles injected  tags like IE 10 did.

Answer (score 1):

Just test in Google Chrome. Both browsers share the WebKit rendering engine. If not, you can virtualize OS X.

Comment: Wrong, while Chrome and Safari share the WebKit/Blink rendering engines they are distinctively forks. You *can* however use the new Chrome clone "Opera" which will let you test multiple versions of Chrome without having to uninstall/reinstall to an insane extent.